# ¿Cual es la utilidad de un token de refresco en el flujo de autenticacion para una api?

Tags: api

No bastaría con generar otro token cuando se expire el que actualmente existe? porque lo que fallo no fue la autenticidad del token (nadie lo manipulo) solo esta expirado y ¿no bastaría con crearle otro al usuario y que luego de crearle ese otro token el servidor le devuelva el recurso sin mandarlo al login?

El flujo de pasos seria el siguiente

- **Cliente** -------token-expirado---->**Servidor**
- **Cliente** <-----nuevo-token-con-recursos- **Servidor**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un token implica mas informacion que la que estas pensando.

Cuando pedis un token original, envias informacion como usuario, password y otras caracteristicas de la sesion para que se otorgue un token de ingreso.

El token de refresco, no necesita todas esas cosas porque el usuario ya ingreso, y entonces solo hace falta actualizar que sigue vivo.

Pedirle al usuario toda la informacion de vuelta (el password no lo guardaste, no?) y enviar todo lo que hace falta para generar un nuevo token, es un gasto de recursos.